# Slick-слайдер: как отцентровать один слайд?

Tags: html, jquery, css, слайдер, slick.js

Установил на сайте slick-слайдер и адаптировал его через responsive под разные размеры экрана. Так получается, что для экранов менее 460px показывать два слайда - много. А один прижимается к левой стрелке, и справа остаётся пустое пространство.

Как сделать, чтобы при показе одного слайда, он был по центру, между стрелками?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Скриншот хотя бы можно? Как вы адаптировали? Вы в курсе что slick сам высчитывает ширину и по дефолту для одного слайда ширина равна ширине блока родителя

Comment: @programmer403, добавил скриншон, не знаю, правда, как это поможет - из описания, вроде, всё ясно

Comment: @programmer403, я же написал - адаптировал через параметр responsive. Ничего slick сам не вычисляет - если не прописывать отдельно каждый breakpoint, он на любом устройстве будет показывать десктопный вариант (то есть все слайды смешивать в кучу друг на друге)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Задайте центрирование для картинки с помощью "margin: 0 auto".
Вот пример
https://jsfiddle.net/5a47jk3L/

```js
$('.single').slick({
  autoplay: true,
  autoplaySpeed: 500
});
```

```css
.single .slide img {
  margin: 0 auto
}
```

```html
<link href="https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/slick/slick.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/slick/slick.js"></script>


  <div class="single">
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6QRX.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6QRX.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6QRX.jpg">
    </div>
```

Comment: А как сделать, что бы я мог разместить справа еще блок, а слайдер был только слева?

Comment: @user364613 вам слайдер нужно чтобы был горизонтальный или вертикальный слева?

Answer (score 1):

Необходимо указать в параметрах centerMode: true

Comment: Постарайтесь давать более развернутые ответы.